# Unable to apply simple CSS to an angular Materials element

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-qbbupb?file=src/app/app.component.scss) the Stackblitz.

I'm trying to apply the CSS `color: blue` to the div with class `mat-button-toggle-label-content`, but its not getting applied.

A similar CSS is getting successfully applied to a parent element called `mat-button-toggle-group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply color to `mat-button-toggle` and keep it inside `mat-button-toggle-group`

### Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-xqgb1m?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

```
mat-button-toggle-group {
  background-color: orange;

  mat-button-toggle { 
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

You can apply the style to `.mat-button-toggle-label-content` but you need to break `Encapsulation`.

Component styles are encapsulated. You can't access component's styles(classes, ids) from outside of the component. You need to pierce into that component and inject the styles like below

**Note:** /deep/ is deprecated and no more recommended. So you can go with above approach. And for more details check [Component Styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

```
mat-button-toggle-group {
  background-color: orange;

  /deep/ .mat-button-toggle-label-content {
      color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't I apply it to the div directly? If I do it through the Developer Tools after the page is loaded, the color gets applied. In other words, why is this not working:

`.mat-button-toggle-label-content{
  color: blue !important
}`

Comment: @Daud component styles are enscapulated and you need to break view encapsulation, so updated my answer with the explanation for your question

Comment: Thanks. Its more clear now. I actually want to set the `line-height` attribute of the (generated) div with class `mat-button-toggle-label-content`. I can't control it by applying this attribute on `mat-button-toggle` as you suggested, because the default line-height of the div is set to 36px by Materials, and it overrides whatever I set on `mat-button-toggle-label-content`

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason for that !

1. Your CSS may not be inserted properly into code
2. The order of material design CSS take over the order of CSS

My solution is that you may need to put !important after color: blue;

it is : color: blue !important;

Comment: !important is not working. You can check the StackBlitz code I linked to, and make changes to correct the issue

Comment: @Daud let me check

Comment: @Daud, inspected it on Chrome, I do not see any CSS with color: blue applied to div tag with class mat-button-toggle-label-content, check the CSS in your source code, it is not imported or placed property. I am very sure about that

Answer (score 0):

Just move it to `styles.scss` and it will work [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-material-components-demo-mvr8mc?file=src/styles.scss).

Comment: Why is it not working in the current setup? All other styles can be applied through component-specific CSS.. so why not this?

Comment: It's a matter of timing, when u place it in the styless.css the execution of this custom css takes place after the execution of the material default styles, so it overrides it.